# ShinyJS as a sort of front-middleware API for other JS framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, r, api, shinyjs

I need an advice. I got a project written in R + ShinyJS. I don't know much about that framework yet but it looks over complicated to me, quirky in terms of UI implementation and hard to test/maintain. I have no time to rewrite it in OpenCPU or similar, but got the idea - to use that as an API service on front end, I mean - to prepare functions which will return R data as JSON objects only, so I could use Angular or React to handle it later in web or phone application (Ionic). Does this approach sound reasonable? Is it possible?